# Prevent user to go ".next" with help of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do real-time checking the input fields from database. I have **java script** below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#emailcheck').load('check-email.php').show();

    $(".next").click(function() {

        $.post('check-email.php', { email: form.email.value },
        function(result) {
            $('#emailcheck').html(result).show();

        });     
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
 <form name="email">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email"><br>
    <div id="emailcheck"></div>
 </form>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary next">Go to step 2</a></p>
```

As you can see when i click `.next` it tells me if email is available or not in `#emailcheck`.

If result I fetch from `check-email.php` is "Available" it's fine.
But the result is "Taken" for example, how can I stop `.next` even to occur? Because I want user to fix the field before go next.

Additional Java Script code I also use for same form:

```
        // jQuery.validate script, does client-side validation
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".next").click(function(){
                var form = $("#myform");
                form.validate({
                    errorElement: 'div',
                    errorClass: 'formerror',
                    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass("has-error");
                    },
                    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass("has-error");
                    },
                    rules: {
                        username: {
                            required: true,
                            minlength: 1,
                            remote: { 
                            url: "check-username.php",
                            async: false,
                            type: "post", }
                        },      
                        email: {
                            required: true,
                            minlength: 1,
                            remote: { 
                            url: "check-email.php",
                            async: false,
                            type: "post", }
                        },

                    },
                    messages: {
                        username: {
                            required: "Username required",
                            remote: "taken",
                        },                  
                        email: {
                            required: "Email required",
                        },                                                      
                    }
                });
                if (form.valid() === true){
                    if ($('#stepusername').is(":visible")){
                        current_fs = $('#stepusername');
                        next_fs = $('#stepemail');
                    }else if($('#stepemail').is(":visible")){
                        current_fs = $('#stepemail');
                        next_fs = $('#stepsuccess');
                    }

                    next_fs.show(); 
                    current_fs.hide();
                }


            });

        });



// prevent sending empty and stuff      
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.form-horizontal').keypress(function (event) {
            if (event.which === 13) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $(".next").trigger('click');
            }
        });
         });

// For server-side validation.
        $(document).ready(function(){   
            $(function(){
                $('input[type=submit]').click(function(){
                    if($("#myform").valid()){

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "sent.php",
                        data: $("#myform").serialize(),

                        beforeSend: function(){
                            $('#stepsuccess').html('Loading...');               
                        },
                        success: function(data){
                            $('#stepsuccess').html(data);
                        }

                    });
                    }
                });
            });
             });
```

Comment: Insert he condition within your success function callback? like: `if(data == "Available") {$('#stepsuccess').html(data);} else { /* Do not go to next step */}`

Comment: Yes that can lead us to solution.  Need to get data from check-email.php. If it's available user should click .next if not need to stay on page. but I don't have that much informat,on unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

What you're actually trying to do is to prevent the default behaviour of the "next" click event. Therefore you should declare your event as `$(".next").click(function(event){` and then on the bottom after the `if (form.valid())` you should add:

```
if (form.valid() === true){
   // everything you originally had here
} else {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is actually confusing. I want to prevent "next" click event if email is already taken. And confusing thing is I wanna do it with also clicking "Next". So in this case your codes only helps to check email field and even though it's available it doesn't go Next, it's only shows "Available."

Comment: I've edited the answer to make it clearer where you should enter it. Did you try it like this?

Comment: Thank you very much, have an up-vote. but everything is same. this is only checks e-mail availability. but next click has another thing to do. Which is going next. I want it to go next only when e-mail is available.